# dataTable editável JSF não mostra atributos do objeto

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, xhtml

Preciso fazer uma atividade com uma lista JSF onde é possível adicionar, editar e excluir os usuários registrados. Tinha conseguido fazer os registros de novas pessoas, mas quando comecei a usar cellEdit pra fazer as edições nos registros, notei que nenhum dos atributos dos objetos aparecem na lista além do ID, e não sei qual é o erro no código. Ao testar, notei que as pessoas estão sim sendo salvas na lista, porém nada aparece na dataTable.

Código do xhtml:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Lista de pessoas</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" style="font-weight:bold" />
            <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{gerenciadorBean.pessoa.nome}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Email:" style="font-weight:bold" />
            <p:inputText id="email" value="#{gerenciadorBean.pessoa.email}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Atualizar" action="#{gerenciadorBean.inserir()}" update="form" icon="pi pi-check" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:dataTable id="display" var="pessoa" value="#{gerenciadorBean.pessoas}" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellCars">]
            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{gerenciadorBean.onCellEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />
            <p:column headerText="ID">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{pessoa.id}"/></f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{pessoa.id}"/></f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Nome">
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{pessoa.nome}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{pessoa.nome}"/></f:facet>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="E-Mail">
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{pessoa.email}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{pessoa.email}"/></f:facet>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:contextMenu for="display" widgetVar="cMenu">   
            <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="pi pi-search" onclick="PF('cellCars').showCellEditor();return false;"/>  
            <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="pi pi-times" onclick="PF('cMenu').hide()"/>  
        </p:contextMenu> 
    </h:form>    
</h:body>
</html>
```

Código do GerenciadorBean:

```js
package br.senai;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class GerenciadorBean {
    
    int id = 1;
    
    private List<Pessoa> listPessoas = new ArrayList();
    
    private Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
    
    public void inserir(){
        pessoa.setId(id);
        listPessoas.add(pessoa);
        pessoa = new Pessoa();
        id++;
    }
    
    public Pessoa getPessoa(){
        return pessoa;
    }
    
    public List<Pessoa> getPessoas(){
        return listPessoas;
    }
    
    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa){
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }
}
```

Código do Pessoa.java:

```
package br.senai;

public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private int id;

    public Pessoa(String nome, String email){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Pessoa(){}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /*  <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" id="display">
                <h:outputText value="#{gerenciadorBean.exibirNome()}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{gerenciadorBean.exibirEmail()}" />
            </h:panelGrid> */
   }
```

Comecei agora em JSF e não sei o que fazer. Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erro bobo!
Somente o ID aparecia pois ele era o único que estava dentro da tag , e por isso ele era o único que imprimia na tabela.